# Debug GlassFish global filter with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, glassfish

I'm developping a filter to handle all request made to my GlassFish v3.01 so I added a configuration in the default-web.xml Everything is working fine, but I'm not able to start debugging session in Eclipse. The compiled jar file is under domain1/lib.

Does someone have an idea on how I could achieve this?

Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error?  Were you able to start a debugging session before but now can't?

Comment: Are you using remote debugging? Can you paste how did you configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem. To be able to debug a GlassFish Global filter with eclipse, we need to create a new debug configuration. This must be a remote java application config with port 9009. You must activate the Debugger in the JVM Setting on the admin page. Then we're able to start the debug configuration and the break points will work just fine.

I found the information here:
http://www.shareyourwork.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/debugging_glassfish_with_eclipse

Thanks.